# right parenthesis missing ora-00907

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    ORG_ROADMARK,
    COUNT(DISTINCT EQUIP_INITIAL||EQUIP_NUM||move_dtm) AS Billing_Count
    FROM CMD_BILLING_INFO
    WHERE move_dtm BETWEEN' 01-FEB-12' AND '29-FEB-12'
    AND (
        (MOVE_TYPE_CD ='ICR' AND EQUIP_STATUS_CD IN ('L','W'))
        OR
        ( MOVE_TYPE_CD ='RLO' AND EQUIP_STATUS_CD ='L' )
        OR
        ( MOVE_TYPE_CD ='RMT' AND EQUIP_STATUS_CD ='W' )
    ) GROUPBY ORG_ROADMARK
) ORDERBY ORG_ROADMARK
```

I am getting missing right parenthesis error for the above sql. Using this sql I was able to get the result for the month period and tried to modify this to get result for last 24 months month by month any suggestions please.

Comment: Please could you format your code to make it easier for people to read. Trust me do this first and then see if you can find the missing )

Answer (score 4):

1. You need a space between the words `GROUP` and `BY` in your `GROUP BY` clause and the words `ORDER` and `BY` in your `ORDER BY` clause.
2. Although it won't cause a syntax error, you almost certainly want don't the single quote right next to the `BETWEEN`.  I would strongly suggest that you also not rely on implicit conversions since someone with different NLS settings may want to run this code.

   ```
   WHERE move_dtm BETWEEN to_date( '01-FEB-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) 
                  AND to_date( '29-FEB-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
   ```

   or

   ```
   WHERE move_dtm BETWEEN date '2012-02-01' AND date '2012-02-29'
   ```

Comment: Dear Justin, Thank you very much for your support now I want to break down this report to show month by month count. Currently I am able to get total count for any given date and now I am trying to get count month wise for any given date. Your advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two causes for the ORA-00907 exception.

The first is, banally, there is a left paranthesis - `(` - without a partnering right parenthesis - `)`.  These can be hard to diagnose by hand, especially in a large SQL statement, but are easy enough if you have a decent IDE with a bracket matching function.

The second cause is a syntax error in a SQL statement which contains brackets.  If we mistype a keyword Oracle treats it as an object name.  This can cause it to throw a number of errors, such as ORA-00905, ORA-00936 and many others in [the 00900 to 01499 range](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#ERRMG102).   ORA-00907 is one of those.  Again, a decent IDE will help here: syntax highlighting can help us to identify typos, by failing to highlight keywords which we have misspelled.

In your particular case it seems likely that your compression of `GROUP BY` into a single word is likely to be the culprit.  You will also need to fix `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seem to be misplaced quote `BETWEEN'`

```
BETWEEN' 01-FEB-12' AND '29-FEB-12'
```